# Product Structure Of $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$, And A Geometric Interpretation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, algebraic-topology, matrix-decomposition

Exercise 6.5 in *Differential Forms In Algebraic Topology* by Bott and Tu asks the reader to prove that there is a direct product decomposition $GL(n,\mathbb{R})=O(n) \times \{\text{positive definite symmetric matrices}\}$. I have the revised third printing, in case that would be relevant w.r.t. errata etc.

Now, I have a doubly-edged question in mind. Firstly, I have to admit that I can't figure out the proof, so any hints or solutions would be nice (I thought of the QR-decomposition of matrices, but realized that it doesn't help the symmetry condition).

Secondly, this result seems to sketch out a complete geometric characterization of the general linear group: Every invertible linear transformation can be expressed as one (positive) eigenbase scaling (because a positive definite symmetric matrix is diagonalizable with all positive eigenvalues) followed by a (composition of) rotation(s) (i.e. "an element of $SO(n)$") and at most one reflection (because that's what orthogonal matrices do). This is a very visually appealing picture if it is correct: Am I correct in this interpretation?

Comment: It also depends on what you mean by "scaling."  Your "scaling" will have to include skew.

Comment: @hkr Thanks for the input, but I'm afraid I don't understand where the skew mappings would come from. Maybe I'm misunderstanding the geometry behind the (orthogonal) diagonalization of the pos. def. symm. matrices? Could you elaborate, or point me towards some reference? (Also, I'm a bit confused as to what "skew" means here: I found "shear mapping" on Wikipedia, and assume that is what you meant)

Comment: @A.Sh, If I take an arbitrary patch on a surface and operate on it with a positive definite symmetric matrix, it both scales and distorts that patch in general, because the scaling need not be equal across all the different dimensions. So as long as you understand that your "scaling" could in fact leave the area (volume) of the patch identical but the patch not congruent, you're fine.

Comment: @hkr Yes, I understand that the scaling may not be the same in all dimensions, since the eigenvectors of the matrix may correspond to different eigenvalues. I think we're on the same wavelength on this one.

Comment: One issue:   The decomposition $Gl(n,\mathbb{R})$ as a product is a decomposition of manifolds, not of Lie groups.  (For example, $O(n)$ is NOT a normal subgroup of $Gl(n,\mathbb{R})$, but it is a normal subgroup of $O(n)\times K$ no matter what group structure you put on $K$).  So I'm not sure what kind of information about the multiplication on $Gl(n,\mathbb{R})$ one can recover from that on the product.